# C# app runs with debugging, but not without

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, debugging

I'm running a (mostly) single threaded program (there's a main thread that does everything, the others only read stuff). I can get the application to run fine in VS2008 after a minor change (I changed the text of a form, and tab order of another form), but I can no longer get it to work outside of the debugger. Does anyone know what would cause this?

**Clarification:** Release mode, launched with debugger (F5) works. Debug mode, lanuched with debugger (F5) works. Debug executable, or release executable launched outside of VS or with Ctrl+F5 fail.

It uses Microsoft's Virtual Earth 3D, and it seems to crash just when the 'ring of hope' (loading ring) is about to complete.

**Event log** says: ".NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000006427F44AA6E) (80131506)"

**Culprit:** this line:

```
        this.loader = PlugInLoader.CreateLoader(this.globeControl.Host);
```

Causes it to fail. However, the form that was working uses the exact same line without an issue. This line is nesseccary for the program to function. I have no idea what it's doing.

**Another Lead** the error seems to be inside the .NET framework. Application worked on another machine, attempting reinstall. **Update:** didn't make a difference, although when I repaired VS it kept telling me Visual Studio was crashing even though I wasn't running it.

---

**Error**
When I launch the program after a couple minutes I get:
Application has generated an exception that could not be handled.

Proccess ID=0x9CC (2508), Thread ID =0xF0C(3852).

Click OK to terminate the application.
Click CANCEL to debug the application.

---

The disassembly is bizarre:

```
0000000077EF2A90  int         3    
0000000077EF2A91  int         3    
0000000077EF2A92  int         3    
0000000077EF2A93  int         3    
0000000077EF2A94  int         3    
0000000077EF2A95  int         3    
0000000077EF2A96  xchg        ax,ax 
0000000077EF2A9A  xchg        ax,ax 
0000000077EF2A9E  xchg        ax,ax 
0000000077EF2AA0  int         3        <-- Crashes here
0000000077EF2AA1  ret
```

It repeats that same code block several times (minus on ax exchanging with itself)

---

**Besides my computer, it has worked on every machine I've tested it on, except for a VM on my machine which won't install the .NET framework because setup downloads 0 bytes out of 0 bytes for the framework)...lovely windows.**

Comment: None, it just crashes. Windows says that the application needs to close.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean by "outside of the debugger"?  Do you mean F5 versus Ctrl+F5 in Visual Studio?  If you go to the bin/debug directory and double click the exe it fails?

Comment: Outside the debugger means that it's not running with debugging, launching with Ctrl+F5 or directly from the executable both cause the application to crash.

Comment: Event log has: .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.3053 - Fatal Execution Engine Error (000006427F44AA6E) (80131506)

Comment: Does the application use any networking?  Like you've allowed VS through a firewall but not the application directly.

Comment: It connects to Microsoft's servers to pull some xml files, but it's done with their API and nothing has changed since my last update to the program, and it was working before.

Comment: Yes, you changed the build.  Make sure the application itself is allowed through the firewall.

Comment: Lets go caveman then. How about putting some msgbox or write log message to file calls in there just sow you know how far it gets before crashing?

Comment: Nothing has changed in their api, which does the connecting. The firewall is not the issue here (I wish it was, it'd be simple to fix)

Comment: I think George is right, have to isolate it.

Comment: I think something is going wrong with the VE3D's API...it crashes when VE3D almost finishes loading although I have a form that still works...

Comment: Use ctrl+alt+e and have it break on all thrown exceptions.

Comment: no change. Doesn't throw an exception in debugger.

Comment: Sorry for throwing darts here, but it's the inside/outside VS clue that makes me think there is a solution here and it's not just an API bug.  How about permissions?  Are you admin all the way through?

Comment: I am. I don't actually think it happened because I changed something, because it worked once before after I changed it. I changed it, compiled it. Ran it (without debugger) and went to lunch. When I came back it wouldn't run again so I restart the computer and now it won't work at all.

Comment: An API update had been released yesterday and I updated today, would it have just now registered the dll changes? Could that be it?

Comment: Very possibly.  It's a pain, but maybe you should build a toy app. that only makes the API calls and see if you still have a working API.

Comment: but when I make another app look just like it, it fails...

Comment: Before you reinstall -- are any of your DLLs deployed to the GAC?  That would take priority over local assemblies and not be a problem when you move machines.

Comment: NB: the jitter works differently when launching from VS, i.e. it ignores tail calls (not that this is an issue here, but this illustrates the difference)

Comment: I think it was global assembly cache. Open c:\windows\assembly with Windows Explorer.

Comment: They are in it should I remove them?

Comment: The references in your project, when you added them, did you use the .NET tab for any of them?  I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure those are the contents of your GAC

Comment: No I did not, I added them from browsing to the C:\Program Folder (x86)\Virtual Earth 3D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it, the .NET 2.0 Framework was corrupt and when I reinstalled it, everything magically started working again.

Comment: Can't figure out how to reinstall. The installer says it's already installed. The Control Panel (Add or Remove Programs) has a Change button that shows a dialog and a progress meter but it doesn't say whether it reinstalled anything or even whether it succeeded or failed. Whatever I tried had no effect on my program's inability to run.

Comment: You need a third party tool, microsoft won't let you remove it. You're looking for dotnetfx or .NET Fix. Google it, it shouldn't be too hard to find. According to microsoft this kind of stuff doesn't happen, therefor you cannot uninstall it.

Comment: Why was this voted down. It is what solved the issue...

Answer (score 7):

I've had similar issues where timing conflicts were causing the failure, and my debugging (breakpoints and stepping through the code) forced the code to run in the correct order.

Comment: That's an interesting idea but can it really be the issue if his application writes on a single thread only?

Comment: no breakpoints in the debugger :(

Comment: You're right, it normally is caused by multi-threading, but sometimes object is doing multi-threading in the background.

Answer (score 7):

Try take off optimizations from the Release build (in the project settings) and see if that helps.

Comment: This resolved the issue for me.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me, but I really don't like it as a long-term solution. Does anyone know exactly what unchecking this changes, and what a better approach would be?

Comment: Here's an interesting blog post about what optimizations do: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/ but honestly if this is causing an issue something deeper is the problem - just look at the other answers. Even a corrupt installation of .net...

Answer (score 4):

I cannot tell you what exactly the problem is, but here's what you could do to get a clue what's really happening. I assume you're using VS2008 or 2005.

1. Switch to release mode
2. Go to Debug\Exceptions, and mark all "Thrown" exceptions, like illustrated here: http://vvcap.net/db/JbWS_tzy2IpBoI7R7amm.htp
3. Run executable in debugger, ignore the warnings from VS that there's no debug info

It does seem that there's a win32 exception thrown some time during execution, but this way or another, you will get one or more messages from debugger explaining what kind of exception happened and where. In most cases those messages make it pretty clear what exactly went wrong

EDIT: One thing I forgot to mention is that unmanaged debugging must also be turned on, such like [here (when you start program directly from IDE)](http://vvcap.net/db/v8CJ-IruecPraqRdxnbj.htp) or [here (when you attach to running process)](http://vvcap.net/db/EMs-yVUsDszMmjgLpX_J.htp)

Comment: someone already asked me to do that, it makes no difference. Nothing is thrown. Nothing. It just crashes outside of a debugger.

Answer (score 3):

[Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/913384) is a support article with that error.  Does that apply?

Perhaps the debugger is eating an excaption the VE3D API is throwing.  In VS, do a ctrl+alt+e and change it to break whenever any exception is thrown.  This can be tedius b/c it will break on all your try catch blocks, but it might give you some information.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/coding4fun/Default.aspx?p=3) is some info. about that PlugInLoader.  It seems to imply it must be called from the FirstFrameRendered eventhandler.  Perhaps one of your forms is doing that and one not?

Comment: No, it's compiled as a .net 3.5 and ran under a user with a profile (me)

Comment: if you call it from the FirstFrameRendered event, it's too late. It's one of the few things that has to be called before that. However, loading plugin's happens after the first frame has been rendered.

Answer (score 1):

Search for #if(DEBUG) directives?
Search for Debug.Assert(?

Have you googled the error?  I found [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/40e8e7e7-d051-49b7-ba2c-509b210a9736) thread (admittedly not horribly helpful)

Comment: It's an app that uses Virtual Earth 3D to create animations, and it was working until I changed a few minor things.

Comment: There are no #if(DEBUG)'s in the app

Answer (score 1):

we found and fixed this issue with MSFT, we faced this problem with VSTO development.
Apply the following patch from MSFT.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/975954

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/974372

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem with exactly the **same behaviour** using a plug-in-system. When loading a plug-in from a `MarshalByRef`-object (see example code below), it seems as if .NET creates a new AppDomain or Context for the loaded assembly. (Can anyone confirm this? I've not found any source regarding this.)

```
public class ProxyAssemblyLoader : MarshalByRefObject {
    public Assembly GetAssembly(string path) {
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
    }
}
```

Furthermore in my case the plug-in loads a different version of the `mscorlib`. (My app is CLR2 and the loaded is CLR4) Afterwards I used the plug-in by reflection and tried to access a value of the new mscorlib, which was loaded from the other application domain. Usually both should be usable because the mscorlib is a commonly used assembly and only loaded once (see [Global Assembly Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)). But it *seems* as if this is not the case. But in general Microsoft [advises to avoid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd153782.aspx#avoid_loading_multiple_versions) that.

I've not exactly figured out what the problem was, but I figured out the call that causes the application to crash without any hint. **Why without any hint?** It crashed without any hint, because the thrown exception was only available in "the other" appdomain and not available for the main/default app domain.

The taken action was just implicit copying the value of another appdomains assembly to a local untyped value (`object`) in the default appdomain. This was enough to get a type identity mismatch error due different versions of the assembly. It seems as if Visual Studio could handle it, but if the application runs standalone it crashes.

This may also explains why you needed to reinstall your .NET. Maybe your installed .NET-Framework was a beta or something like that, which contained a minor difference.

In conclusion some general solutions for the problem could be:

- Avoid using different versions of assemblies with different versions of the same type.
- In other cases may try to load both assemblies inside the same appdomain. (As far as possible regarding the probing context.)
- A solution for [cross appdomain communication could be serialization](http://www.microsoft.com/india/msdn/events/Understanding%20Remoting%20Better.ppt_) of the values.
- (Make sure that the correct .NET-Framework Non-Beta Version is installed.)

Answer (score 0):

One thing left I think is to use WinDbg to try and debug it. Here are some links on how to use it:

1. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/windbg_part1.aspx
2. http://blogs.msdn.com/johan/archive/2007/11/13/getting-started-with-windbg-part-i.aspx
3. http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/ (good blog about debugging in general in windbg)

Thinking about it, it could also be some service or something that's clashing. Try stopping all unneeded services and closing unneeded programs (including startup ones) and see what happens then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue with one of my console applications. I determined that it was my antivirus (Avast) that was causing the issue.

Add the `BIN` folder to the exclusion list and disable "DeepScreen".
Then rebuild the project and try again!