# Cannot launch applications outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having a really strange problem that I just can't figure out.  Things I compile in Visual Studio 2015 (C# projects in WinForms and WPF) will not launch outside of Visual Studio.  This includes a project that is completely new and untouched.  As in, create a new WPF Application, build in debug and release.  Go to containing folders click on EXEs and...nothing.

When I run them I get 3 processes appearing in Task Manager (named the same as my application) than cannot be killed (through task manager or command prompt) and nothing else occurs.  Nothing in event viewer that seems to correspond to the app.  I've attached an instance of VS 2015 to the process and I get the following message: WpfApplication.exe has triggered a break point.  Pressing Break takes me to a screen that tells me no debug information is available and pressing continue has no visible effects (I can occasionally see slight movement in the cpu % but not a lot else).  Any attempt to stop debugging will cause visual studio to hang and when I end its process VS closes but its memory is not freed up according to Task Manager.  All of these same things occur when building in VS2013 and attempting to run outside of VS.  Everything runs just fine when run in debug mode inside Visual Studio but outside of it...not a chance.

I literally have no idea where to proceed from here.  I can find no error messages or clues to point me in a direction to look.  Is there something I'm missing/doing wrong?  What steps can I take from here to find the source of the problem?

I've considered it may be something wrong with my computer but I want to explore the possibilities before I do something drastic like a clean install.  If the prevailing opinion lies that way then I'll seek help elsewhere!

tl;dr:  launching the exe of a compiled application results in no running application and no obvious error messages, how can I proceed from here?

Comment: are you familiar with how to deploy .net applications.. do the other machines have the .net version / assemblies etc installed on the target machine..? just because it runs fine on your machine does not mean that you can just copy over to another machine expect it to run.. do a MSDN search on How to Deploy .NET applications

Comment: sorry, meant to include that this is on the same machine.

Comment: To clarify: neither Debug nor Release configs run when you click on the exe in Windows Explorer? Do they both run in the debugger? What about launching in VS without the debugger, hitting Ctrl-F5?

Comment: Correct, debug and release both have the same symptoms when launched from explorer. Both run with debugger. Ctrl-F5 results in VS hanging, it still says running in task manager but it responds to no further input.

Comment: Have you looked at this case? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738327/c-sharp-app-runs-with-debugging-but-not-without

Comment: I have looked at it but didn't really find anything to help me in there. I briefly managed to get debug exes working outside of VS but there wasn't a specific action that seemed to relate.  After a restart they don't work any more. Release exes still don't never worked. I get nothing at all appearing in the event log to suggest what might be going wrong. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the dot net framework and the situation remains unchanged.  I'm going to try removing the .net framework again and visual studio and try to reinstall it all. Other stuff works fine, just not what I compile.

Comment: OK, once again I'm kind of at fault here.  Something I should have tried several hours ago was turning off the antivirus - I'd completely forgotten how annoying it could be.  Turns out Avast hates me and everything I do but doesn't feel the need to communicate that to me.  Turning off Avast means everything launches fine so for some reason its stopping my stuff from running but not saying a thing about it to me.  Which is frustrating.  Sorry for the waste of time!  Lesson learned and probably forgotten by tomorrow.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to post an answer to this because I found out what was wrong but it probably isn't useful to have it hanging around so I'll just delete the question at some point soon.

The main lesson to remember is that the main purpose of anti virus software is to frustrate you as much as possible and if something weird is happening try turning it off briefly and see what happens.  You'll probably find that things are now working correctly.

EDIT: I should restate this in a more serious fashion.

Anti virus can sometimes affect things in unexpected ways and turning it off temporarily can save you a lot of time.  Keep it up to date too, mine was a version or so old and was not functioning correctly.  I updated it and the deep scan now functions as expected rather than silently failing.

Comment: I don't really think that "the main purpose of anti virus software is to frustrate you as much as possible"... If you truly want to provide an answer to this question (and it's perfectly acceptable to do so), you should at least try to be factual in the answer, and avoid these kind of snarky remarks.

Comment: I don't think you should delete this. These sorts of frustrating problems happen to all of us now and then. In your case the virus checker was the cause. That might not be true for everyone, but your answer shows that it can be.

Comment: I apologise for the snarkiness.  I was feeling very snarky at the time.