# Deployment of a C# Windows Forms Application

Tags: c#, .net, setup-deployment

I am attempting to create a simple install-able form application using Visual Studio Community 2015.

I have followed this walkthrough: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k3bb4tfd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

As the setup project templates were not originally present, I used https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9 to add them.

I am able to successfully make the installer, as well as successfully install the app. However, when I try to run the application (by going to its installed folder), windows explorer just sits there,  like it is trying to do something, but never does. I end up needing to restart the computer in order to cancel this process that never starts.

The same behavior is seen when I try to run the built application on its own, without the installer, running the executable generated from building the actual application. (diving down into the bin/ of the project).

I have seen similar behavior from new, indev programs before (https://github.com/Storj/driveshare-gui/releases), but would not know if the issues are necessarily related.

The app itself runs fine when being debugged by Visual Studio. I used the Visual C# "Windows Forms Application" template to create the original app.

Please let me know if there is anything you would need to see, I would not know.

**Program.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Parking_Variable_Editor {
    static class Program {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
    }
}
```

**Constructor & onload from MainForm.cs (the only form in the project)**

```
public MainForm() {
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void onShown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    refreshForm();
}
```

**Update:**

I have gotten the project to run without debugging. I did this by instead refreshing the form when it is shown, as onLoad seemed to try to do it before things were initialized. Now, however, the same issue is only happening for the installed application.

Comment: If the app doesn't run properly when you start it from the bin directory then it is quite pointless to hope it will be better after you create an installer for it.  There is not a scrap of relevant information in this question to help us help you.

Comment: What would be relevant and helpful? @HansPassant

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Snappawapa refreshForm() is likely the problem.  See my comments on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen this problem before -- and others have too:
[C# app runs with debugging, but not without](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738327/c-sharp-app-runs-with-debugging-but-not-without)

Here are some ideas.
Most likely when the app starts it is failing when attempting instantiate your main form.  If you run in Visual Studio, it may self-heal the problems you've created and make you think it'll run by double-clicking the EXE.

1. Look in the constructor of your main Windows Form.
2. Look in the OnLoad of your windows form.
3. Set a breakpoint in the Program.cs file where the your main form is instantiated and then step into the form code -- run using F5 in visual studio so it will run the debug copy.
4. Post the code from your Program.cs and your main form constructor and OnLoad methods so we can see it.

**Edit**:

The RefreshForm() code is 99% most likely the problem.  Need to see that code, but I'm betting if you comment out that line the app will run.

Comment: Thanks for a constructive answer, I have posted the requested code, and have tried debugging with the breakpoint. I noticed nothing unusual.

Comment: Okay, so RefreshForm() is 99% likely to be the problem. You are doing something there before the form is even constructed.  Please post that code or coment it out and try again. You'll be fixed.

Comment: I just tried taking `refreshForm()` out, and no change to anything,

Comment: @Snappawapa Okay, so you need to see if there is something entirely wrong with your .NET installation.  You could download my simple form app from : http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1066094/ProcessWatcher-Leverage-ManagementEventWatcher-to  Build that and try running.  If you can't run that, then you have a installation problem.  Also, you can try creating a entirely new project and building that and seeing if it builds and runs outside of studio.

Comment: check my update, got it working without debugging, but now it is having the same issue when installed.

Comment: @Snappawapa That's probably just because your install location is referencing the old exe or when you rebuilt hte installation, you built with the old version of the exe.  If you fixed it and it runs it is unlikely the installation causes the same problem to occur.  Do a Build...Clean..Rebuild...All... then rebuild your installation package too. It'll prob be fine then.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is take that RefreshForm() method and put it in a OnLoad event, wrapped in a try..catch block

```
try
{
    RefreshForm();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

That way if RefreshForm is the issue then you will get the reason, and the app will at least start.

If you don't see a message box, then it is something more fundamental.

Comment: You could also litter your app with message boxes, seeing as you are just starting out with the app, with a message saying what stage it got to. This will give you a breadcrumb to trace the issue.

Comment: I just tried the try/catch in the onload, no error is caught & shown, even when run outside of debugging. (and I know the form is refreshing as well, when run from debug). Everything works well, except when run outside of debug, where it does not run at all, seemingly

Comment: @Snappawapa Yes, that is what I expected. You cannot catch the exception.  It is a chicken/egg problem: which came first? You are trying to do something in your refreshForm() call before the Form is fully constructed.  Are you having difficulty commenting out that line?  Show us that code and I can tell you more specifically about why it is occurring.  I've seen this same type of code run on numerous machines and then fail one 1 machine.  It's a timing thing -- but your code has to be changed.  The timing thing is why it works in VSTudio -- it self-heals it.

Comment: @Snappawapa was the try..catch in form load rather than constructor? It is important that it is - you don't want business logic and method calls in the constructor

Comment: After taking everything out from both the onLoad and the constructor, it finally runs without issue. It looks to me that the OnLoad is still happening before the form itself is presented.

Comment: @Snappawapa that was my point. You have to know exactly the order of events for form construction, loading, etc.  So you can go ahead and mark mine as the answer. :)

Comment: @RobKing Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  check my update, got it working without debugging, but now it is having the same issue when installed.

Comment: @Snappawapa feel free to mark this as the answer  :)

Answer (score -1):

So it is clear for future reference, what solved the problem:

1. removed function that played with form elements from constructor and onload, moved it to an onShow event-tied function
2. Cleaned and rebuilt everything.
3. I also needed to add "Runtime Implementation from 'project name here'" and "Localized resources from 'Project name here'" in order for it to run. (this was not specified in the guide I followed)